# How to create the ADT header for a Map and a Set in Scala

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types

I am new to Scala and would like to know how to implement the header for a Map and/for a Set.
As an example I implemented the one for Binary tree in the following way :

```
sealed trait Tree[+T]
case object Leaf extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Branch[T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
```

But I am still confused on how to create the same header for a Map and a Set.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. What is a header for you? Why you want to implement an ADT for **Map** and **Set**?

Comment: Not every type is an ADT. There are different ways to model a set: HashSet, TreeSet, `A => Boolean`. Similarly for maps.

Comment: By the header I meant just the blueprint of how the data are stored inside without methods, the why ? I am not trying to reinvent the wheel but exercises myself with ADT because I am new to Scala and would like to play around with them by implementing some basic popular methods(algorithm) that we find in those provided by Scala @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @Pbk243 the common examples are **List** and **Tree**. - **Set** can be implemented as a **Function** that returns a **Boolean**. And a _(Sorted)_ **Map** can be implemented in terms of a **Tree**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you I see the concept I was thinking may be it would be something like : **sealed trait MyMap[A,+B]** as I saw from the official documentation website

Comment: @Pbk243 from where did you saw that? note that I provided common implementations as learning exercises but the std lib **Map** and **Set** are very different from that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez is saw it from **https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html** official repository  **https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.4/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L22**

Comment: @Pbk243 you can see it is a normal `trait` not a `sealed trait`, it is just normal OOP polymorphism, not a functional ADT.